# Connecting to multiple buckets on Couchbase cluster with Spring

Tags: spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

in my project I have a Couchbase cluster. I also have different buckets for different datas. I want to configure them in `CouchbaseConfiguration` file as it is specified in[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.configuration) but I got `NullPointerException`.

I am using `spring-data-couchbase` in pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this is my CouchbaseConfiguration file.

```
package com.example.cbase.configuration;

import com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket;
import com.couchbase.client.java.Cluster;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration;

@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfiguration extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
    @Override
    public String getConnectionString() {
        return "10.10.56.12,10.10.56.13,10.10.56.14";
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserName() {
        return "user1";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return "password1!";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBucketName() {
        return null;
    }
    @Bean
    public Bucket testCaseBucket(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.bucket("testCaseBucket");
    }

    @Bean
    public Bucket testRunBucket(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.bucket("testRunBucket");
    }

    @Bean
    public Bucket userLogBucket(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.bucket("userLogBucket");
    }

    @Bean
    public Bucket scheduleBucket(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.bucket("scheduleBucket");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration, you need to override configureReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping() and configureRepositoryOperationsMapping()

You can find this in

```
git clone git@github.com:spring-projects/spring-data-couchbase.git
cd spring-data-couchbase
```

./src/test/java/org/springframework/data/couchbase/domain/Config.java

```
@Override
public void configureReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping(ReactiveRepositoryOperationsMapping baseMapping) {
    try {
        ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate personTemplate = myReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("protected"),
        (MappingCouchbaseConverter) (baseMapping.getDefault().getConverter()));
        baseMapping.mapEntity(Person.class, personTemplate); // Person goes in "protected" bucket
        ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate userTemplate = myReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("mybucket"),
        (MappingCouchbaseConverter) (baseMapping.getDefault().getConverter()));
        baseMapping.mapEntity(User.class, userTemplate); // User goes in "mybucket"
        // everything else goes in getBucketName() 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

@Override
public void configureRepositoryOperationsMapping(RepositoryOperationsMapping baseMapping) {
    try {
        CouchbaseTemplate personTemplate = myCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("protected"),
        (MappingCouchbaseConverter) (baseMapping.getDefault().getConverter()));
        baseMapping.mapEntity(Person.class, personTemplate); // Person goes in "protected" bucket
        MappingCouchbaseConverter cvtr = (MappingCouchbaseConverter)baseMapping.getDefault().getConverter();
        CouchbaseTemplate userTemplate = myCouchbaseTemplate(myCouchbaseClientFactory("mybucket"),
        (MappingCouchbaseConverter) (baseMapping.getDefault().getConverter()));
        baseMapping.mapEntity(User.class, userTemplate); // User goes in "mybucket"
        // everything else goes in getBucketName() 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

// do not use reactiveCouchbaseTemplate for the name of this method, otherwise the value of that bean
// will be used instead of the result of this call (the client factory arg is different)
public ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate myReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(CouchbaseClientFactory couchbaseClientFactory,
        MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter) {
    return new ReactiveCouchbaseTemplate(couchbaseClientFactory, mappingCouchbaseConverter,
            new JacksonTranslationService(), getDefaultConsistency());
}

// do not use couchbaseTemplate for the name of this method, otherwise the value of that been
// will be used instead of the result from this call (the client factory arg is different)
public CouchbaseTemplate myCouchbaseTemplate(CouchbaseClientFactory couchbaseClientFactory,
        MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter) {
    return new CouchbaseTemplate(couchbaseClientFactory, mappingCouchbaseConverter, new JacksonTranslationService(),
            getDefaultConsistency());
}

// do not use couchbaseClientFactory for the name of this method, otherwise the value of that bean will
// will be used instead of this call being made ( bucketname is an arg here, instead of using bucketName() )
public CouchbaseClientFactory myCouchbaseClientFactory(String bucketName) {
    return new SimpleCouchbaseClientFactory(getConnectionString(), authenticator(), bucketName);
}
```